# Formik component changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I am using Formik with an array, where the items are being passed from a parent and retrieved like this:

```
updateState (){
    this.state.choices = this.props.choices
    this.state.questionId = this.props.questionId
  }
  render() {
    this.updateState()
    var choices = this.state.choices
    console.log(choices)
    return ( ...
```

I am originally initializing the values as empty or 0:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      choices : [],
      questionId: 0
    };
  }
```

While this seems like it should work, I am getting the error that a component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.  understand this is due to my use of this.state but I'm unsure how to actually fix this.

What I have done so far, since I am using Formik, is change my export to look like this:

```
  export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({
    choices: [{
    id: '',
    value: '',
    weight: '',
    impact: ''}]
  }),
})(Choices)
```

It's unclear if I should be mapping props at all, or if I should be using something more like:

```
export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({

    id: '',
    value: '',
    weight: '',
    impact: ''
  }),
})(Choices)
```

All I know is that I am unable to click to push a new object onto the array that I am working with, so the functionality is basically frozen until I can figure out the state of the un/controlled input element.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: You should not mutate state like `this.state.choices`. Use `setState` instead, set it in the constructor  or just use the props directly if you can.

Comment: Changed that, still getting the uncontrolled error. Good spot, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing the HTML and the {choices[index].id} bits cleared this error.

E.g.:

```
<div className="col">
                        <label htmlFor={choices[index].id}>{choices[index].id}</label>
                        <Field name={choices[index].id} placeholder={choices[index].value} type="text"/>
                        <ErrorMessage name={choices[index].id} component="div" className="field-error" />
                      </div>
```